# Ping: "Destination Host Unreachable" even though ARP request succeeds

Tags: linux, ping, arp

I have a wired interface with a static IP configured. Pinging the gateway results in "Destination Host Unreachable".

```
PING 10.3.3.246 (10.3.3.246) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 10.3.3.8 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
From 10.3.3.8 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
From 10.3.3.8 icmp_seq=3 Destination Host Unreachable
From 10.3.3.8 icmp_seq=4 Destination Host Unreachable
From 10.3.3.8 icmp_seq=5 Destination Host Unreachable
^C
```

I wireshark I can see the ARP request being replied to immediately. The ARP request is retried every second and every time it gets an immediate reply.

It seems that the ARP reply is not accepted for some reason. Anyone have an idea what could be going on?

Comment: A firewall can either reject or silently drop. Not related to the arp table.

Answer (score 0):

The problem turned out to be that the ARP replies arrived with a VLAN tag (when no VLAN tagging was expected at all.) There was a problem with the switch.

Posting this an answer so people know to check for unexpected VLAN tags in situations like these.